# map_partitions runs twice when storing dask dataframe in parquet and records are counted

Tags: python, dask, parquet, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I have a dask process that runs a function on each dataframe partition. I let `to_parquet` do the
`compute()` that runs the functions.

But I also need to know the number of records in the `parquet` table. For that, I use `ddf.map_partitions(len)`. Problem is that when I count the number of records, a `compute()` is done again on the dataframe, and that makes the map_partitions functions run again.

What should be the approach to run map_partitions, save the result in parquet, and count the number of records?

```
def some_func(df):
    df['abc'] = df['def'] * 10
    return df

client = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')

ddf.map_partitions(some_func) # some_func executes twice for each partition

ddf.to_parquet('/some/folder/data', engine='pyarrow') 

total = ddf.map_partitions(len).compute().sum()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One potential problem is line:

```py
ddf.map_partitions(some_func)
```

Here, the instruction to dask is to map partitions, but there is no instruction to store the results of this operation. Hence, the code should probably be:

```py
# this will store the modified dataframe as ddf
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(some_func)
```

Next, running `.to_parquet` will evaluate (compute) the dataframe `ddf` and discard it from memory, so the subsequent `.compute` will re-compute the dataframe.

This can be expensive, so some of the possible solutions are:

1. if `ddf` can fit into memory of workers, then the `ddf` could be persisted to avoid recomputing:

```py
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(some_func)
ddf = ddf.persist()
ddf.to_parquet('/some/folder/data', engine='pyarrow') 
total = ddf.map_partitions(len).compute().sum()
```

2. re-defining `ddf` in terms of computed data. Here, `dask` will use the stored parquet files (that were computed) and load information from them:

```py
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(some_func)
ddf = ddf.persist()
ddf.to_parquet('/some/folder/data', engine='pyarrow')

# create a new ddf based on the computed values
ddf = dd.read_parquet('/some/folder/data')
total = ddf.map_partitions(len).compute().sum()
```

3. another solution could be to modify `some_func` to store the results on the fly and return `len`. The rough pseudocode is:

```py
path_out = 'some/template_path/for/parquet/{number}.parquet'

def some_func(df, partition_info=None):
    df['abc'] = df['def'] * 10
    # this uses partition number to create an appropriate path
    path_save_parquet = path_out.format(number=partition_info['number'])
    df.to_parquet(path_save_parquet)
    return len(df)

# this will compute total length and save the computation in the process
total = ddf.map_partitions(some_func).compute().sum()
```